# change focus from input to div in angular 4 and scroll up and down content with arrow keys

Tags: angular

I have an angular 4 project and in my component I have an input that when type in use API service and loading result in `spans` of a `div` that  have `overflow-y: auto` property in CSS, Now I want to change focus from `input` to `div` and can scroll content of it when I press arrow key down.

```
 <input class="origin-input" type="text" placeholder ="origin"/>
  <div class="result-box" style="overflow-y: auto; height :300px">
  <span>result-item</span>
  <span>result-item</span>
  <span>result-item</span>
</div>
```

Comment: Have you tried adding a `(keydown)` event binding to your `input` tag?

Comment: @user184994    no , how can use it ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The first part of the problem is to listen to the events. Angular offers a nice way of binding to key events. Just change your input tag like so:

```
<input class="origin-input" type="text" (keydown.arrowdown)="focus()" placeholder ="origin"/>
```

This will call our focus function everytime the down arrow is pressed and the input has focus.

Now, we need to define our `focus` function.

Firstly, change your HTML so that we can reference the div, and add a `tabindex` to it so that it can receive focus:

```
<div #box tabIndex="1" class="result-box" style="overflow-y: auto; height :100px">
```

Then, in the ts file, get a reference to that div using `ViewChild`:

```
@ViewChild("box") box;
```

Finally, we can create the `focus` function

```
focus() {
  this.box.nativeElement.focus();
}
```

[**Here is a StackBlitz example**](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-kgbr9t?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts)